# cordova ios version 6.2 white screen on launch (woking on ios 5.1.1)

Tags: ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-ios

I spent some time trying to understand why this white screen is showing up but since I'm new to Cordova I have no clue what else to try... This is what i did :

- removed every Cordova plugin
- tried different ways of using splash screen but I'm new to Cordova and could only make it work on android or iOS <=5.1.1
  I might have misunderstood something, here is my config.xml

```
<widget id="app.bee.api" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>App</name>
    <description> demo app</description>
    <author email="author@gmail.com">author</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

    <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="localhost"  /> 

    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when switching to iOS 6+, UIWebView is deprecated. Which also means that  WKWebView is the new default and the splash screens plugin is not required anymore is you target iOS only :

> Note: iOS implementation has been moved to the core framework. If
> using cordova-ios@5 or earlier, use cordova-plugin-splashscreen@5 If
> using cordova-ios@6 or later, use cordova-plugin-splashscreen@6. If
> developing exclusively for the iOS platform, this plugin can be
> uninstalled.

[Source](https://cordova.apache.org/2021/02/07/deprecate-wkwebview-engine.html)

Also the format has changed in the XML for splashscreens. You should read

[UIWebView Deprecated](https://cordova.apache.org/2021/02/07/deprecate-wkwebview-engine.html)

[Cordova iOS 6+](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/23/cordova-ios-6.1.0.html)